# What is the difference between the jobs and ps commands in linux?

Tags: linux, unix

Please tell me the differences in information displayed by two commands jobs and ps in unix operating system?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  i was checking the commands ps and jobs.I was expecting both should show the current running jobs, but ps is showing some extra information. I want to know what does these commands exactly do. ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`jobs` is a shell builtin. It tells you about the jobs that the current shell is managing. It can give you information that is internal to the shell, like the job numbers (which you can use in shortcuts like `fg %2`) and the original command line as it appeared before variable expansions.

`ps` is an external command which can tell you about all the processes running on the system. (By default it only shows a small subset, but there are options to select larger sets of processes to display.) It doesn't know about the shell-internal stuff.

Answer (score -1):

jobs: shows the current jobs living in this terminal
as example ->

```
gedit &
jobs
```

this will show u gedit is running atm.

if you close the terminal, gedit dies too, you can use `disown` so it wont die.

`ps` is a totally different thing, its a process table display tool.